# Mysqli query not displaying any result set

Tags: php, mysqli

I have he below code. My issue is if I echo the `mysqli_num_rows()` it shows me 2  meaning it has 2 rows the query is returning. However for some reason I can not get any of the variables from any of the columns to show on the page.

There are no errors in console or anything; just blank screen?

My code

```
    $blogsql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT image AS blogimage, url_key, short_description, publish_date FROM mageplaza_blog_post 
                               where enabled = 1 order by publish_date desc LIMIT $start, $limit");
    $rowsnummber = mysqli_num_rows($blogsql);
    //echo "$rowsnummber<br />";
   // die();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($blogsql))
     {
         echo $row['blogimage'] . 'hh<br />';
     }
?>
```

So the above is not even showing the hh ??

Comment: did you try mysqli_fetch_array($blogsql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: Have you not checked for errors? Via php and / or the query?

Comment: just use `http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php` this ;)

Comment: beware of SQL injection risks if your start and end variables come from the client - make sure you sanitise the values and ensure they're definitely integers.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_fetch_array` returns a numerically indexed array so `extract` would not produce the variables with your column names.

For your purpose you can replace it with `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: you probably mean mysqli_ not mysql_

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($blogsql)){
    echo $row['url_key'] . '<br />';
}
```

reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: I updated my code to match sietse85 but still not showing anything its strange.